# Firebase and picasso not loading users information on first load

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, picasso

I have a simple project with a navigation drawer that loads the users name, email and profile picture when they log in using a google account,  This all gets set in the navigation drawer.  The issue I'm facing is that it does not load the users picture, name or email when they first launch the app and log in, if you close the app and reopen it will then show the users information.  My code is below:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.mts2792.swissarmytools.R;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import model.CircleTransform;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d("User logged in", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d("User logged out", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                // ...
            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {

            // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
            String name = user.getDisplayName();
            String email = user.getEmail();
            Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();

            // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
            // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
            // FirebaseUser.getToken() instead.
            String uid = user.getUid();

            TextView nameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentUser);
            TextView emailTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentEmail);
            ImageView currentPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.currentPic);

            nameTextView.setText(name);
            emailTextView.setText(email);

            Picasso.with(this)
                    .load(photoUrl)
                    .resize(175, 175)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_account)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_account)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .transform(new CircleTransform())
                    .into(currentPic);
//            Picasso.with(this).load(photoUrl).into(currentPic);

            Log.v("Logged in", name);
            Log.v("Email: ", email);

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_compass) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Heres some screenshots to show what I'm talking about:
First load:

[image: 1]

After the second load:

[image: 2]

Comment: you can try placing placeholder in Picasso until actual image URL loads from the server

Comment: @PratikVyas I have a placeholder there but its not an issue with it loading from the server, I can see the information in the logs.  The issue I have is it won't show up in my textviews or imageview until I reload the screen.

Comment: why do you put the code in onCreateOption menu?

Comment: If there's a better place to put it I'm all ears, I put it there because I'm trying to load the information in the navigation drawer.  I'm not very experienced at coding.

Comment: Put your code in onCreate

Comment: okay can you please share your entire activity after that i can tell where to put that code snippet

Comment: @PratikVyas ok, I added the remainder of my code besides my oncreate method.

Comment: @MitchDavis try my answer  if it helps and tell me what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Drawer state change listener might help you out, here is a stripped down version of your code, I have kept the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` as is., you might want to update that

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

 private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
 FirebaseUser FBuser;
 private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


  DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
  ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
   this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
  drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
  toggle.syncState();

  NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
  navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

  mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
  FBuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

  mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
   @Override
   public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
    FBuser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    fetchUpdateUserData();
    if (FBuser != null) {
     // User is signed in
     Log.d("User logged in", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + FBuser.getUid());
    } else {
     // User is signed out
     Log.d("User logged out", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
    }
    // ...
   }
  };

  mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener)

 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

  // Fetch Data if FBuser is not null
  fetchUpdateUserData();

  DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
  drawer.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {}

   @Override
   public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {}

   @Override
   public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {}

   @Override
   public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
    // STATE_IDLE, STATE_DRAGGING or STATE_SETTLING.
    if (newState == STATE_DRAGGING || newState == STATE_SETTLING)
    // Fetch Data if FBuser is not null
     fetchUpdateUserData();
   }
  });

  drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

  return true;
 }



 public void fetchUpdateUserData() {
  if (FBuser != null) {

   // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
   String name = FBuser.getDisplayName();
   String email = FBuser.getEmail();
   Uri photoUrl = FBuser.getPhotoUrl();

   // The FBuser's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
   // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
   // FirebaseUser.getToken() instead.
   String uid = FBuser.getUid();

   TextView nameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentUser);
   TextView emailTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentEmail);
   ImageView currentPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.currentPic);

   nameTextView.setText(name);
   emailTextView.setText(email);

   Picasso.with(this)
    .load(photoUrl)
    .resize(175, 175)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_account)
    .error(R.drawable.ic_account)
    .centerCrop()
    .transform(new CircleTransform())
    .into(currentPic);
   //            Picasso.with(this).load(photoUrl).into(currentPic);

  } else {
   nameTextView.setText("");
   emailTextView.setText("");
   Picasso.with(this)
    .load(R.drawable.ic_account)
    .resize(175, 175)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_account)
    .error(R.drawable.ic_account)
    .centerCrop()
    .transform(new CircleTransform())
    .into(currentPic);
  }
 }

}
```

PS: please refactor the code before posting and use `Fields` rather than `localVariables` for `DRY (don't repeat yourself)` coding

Answer (score 0):

Hello Davis try this in your code if it helps 
When your activity first loads onCrate method will work and while coming from background to foreground onResume will work

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getUserDetails();

        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentUser);
        TextView emailTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentEmail);
        ImageView currentPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.currentPic);

        nameTextView.setText(name);
        emailTextView.setText(email);

        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(photoUrl)
                .resize(175, 175)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_account)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_account)
                .centerCrop()
                .transform(new CircleTransform())
                .into(currentPic);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getUserDetails();
    }

    public void getUserDetails(){
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {

            // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
            name = user.getDisplayName();
            email = user.getEmail();
            photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();
            uid = user.getUid();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @ Mitch Davis did that helped?

Comment: What do I add in onCreateOptionsMenu?  Just the getMenuInflater?

Comment: comment your code section  in onCreateOptionsMenu and try running the app

Comment: I added all my code in my question, if I comment the code in onCreateOptionsMenu I get a NullPointerException

Comment: please share that exception entire exception

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: @Pratik Can you explain why you have put the same code in two different life cycle? Seems very interesting! :)

Comment: he has a loading problem and onResume method is called when the application is paused what's interesting in it :).

Comment: @MitchDavis now try this if still don;t work uncomment the onCreateOptions Menu code , we will work on code optimization later when application get soother run

Comment: In your previous edit, you just copied and pasted same code in two different lifecycle. In this new edition, you are again using getUserDetails method twice. This is creating redundancy. See carefully - you are using setText/loadPhoto etc in oncreate, so it will set the values what it gets from the first call of getUserDetails() inside onCreate. There is no effect of getUserDetails() in your 2nd call inside onResume. I hope you got my point.

Comment: @SudipPodder I wasn't putting entire code there, I was giving him rough idea so that he get's the value and he manages in his code and I know onCreate has set Text and onResume can get only value but my intention was just to give him idea and he will manage rest, as earlier he didn't provide entire activity so it was hard to look where he was lacking

Comment: @PratikVyas I updated my question with the entire activity code, can you use that to explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: @MitchDavis try putting everything in onCreate i can give you only idea as i don't know your entire code

Comment: @PratikVyas that is my entire code, I will try putting it in oncreate and let you know.